# IIS suddenly refuses to serve PDF or RTF files; still serves DOC files

Tags: iis

Yesterday everything was working just fine but now today when I try to access a PDF or RTF file served by IIS, I get a 404 error (when accessing it through HTTPS) or a 403 error (when accessing it through HTTP). I can still access DOC files hosted by this server. What could have possibly changed to prevent the PDF and RTF files from loading? They are being generated properly in a folder that belongs to a virtual directory being requested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had two similarly named folders and the files were being written to one folder and read from the other, which of course did not contain them because they were actually in the first folder. Fixing this issue solved my problem. Must have goofed up a configuration setting somewhere that this broke...